# How to set margin for a single cell inside stack panel for multiple controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, jquery-ui-accordion

I need the textbox1 control ought to put by lable1 and textbox2 control ought to put alongside lable2. I am utilizing single cell from a Grid for this whole control allignment. i can't drag and place the controls wherever i need. is there some other conceivable approach to drag and place my controls inside a cell in grid?

Here's my XAML code..

```
<Grid Background="#BFBFBF">
        <StackPanel  Margin="2,2,2,2"  >
            <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2"    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                    <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

               <!-- 1st Content-->
               <Border  Margin="4,2,2,2"  BorderBrush="#FF0100A3" Grid.Row="0"    CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"   VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Height="30"   MouseLeftButtonDown="brdSectionOne_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5E68CE" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF5B64CA" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF000C82" Offset="0.356"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <TextBlock Text="Section 1" Grid.ColumnSpan ="2"  Foreground="White" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13"  Margin="8,5,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Normal" Cursor="Hand" />
            </Border>
            <StackPanel x:Name="spnlFirstSection"  Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Height="436" Margin="3,35,3,0"  >
                <Border  Margin="1,1,1,1"  CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"   VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Height="430" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FF4C4BEE" >
                    <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan ="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="445" Margin="6,6,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                        <Label x:Name="lbl_1" Content="Label 1" Margin="50,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.895,0" FontSize="14"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Margin="300,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="textbox1" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="250" FontSize="18"/>
                        <Label x:Name="lbl_2" Content="Label 2" Margin="50,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.895,0" FontSize="14"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Margin="300,30,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="textbox2" Height="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="250" FontSize="18"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="Section 1 Content" Grid.ColumnSpan ="2"  Foreground="#FF000000" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13"  Margin="6,6,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Normal" Cursor="Hand" Height="445" />-->
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: WTF is that tag? wpf & jquery in same freakin question? Dude you seriously need to learn the framework & indeed the language before you attempt to create something. This is NOT JqueryUI. You cannot expect things to work like they do in web. Perhaps you should make this in php?

Answer (score 1):

A StackPanel stacks either Vertically (default) or Horizontally. Like so:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Foo"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Bar"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Will render:
Foo
Bar

While

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Foo"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Bar"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Will render:
Foo Bar

If you want something to look like a Grid you should use a Grid! So if you want something like this:
LabelOne: Foo
LabelTwo: Bar

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="LabelOne:" /> <!-- Grid.Row and Grid.Column default to 0 -->
    <Label Content="LabelTwo:" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Text="Foo" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Text="Bar" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

You could also try and nest StackPanels like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="LabelOne:" />
        <Label Content="LabelTwo:" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Foo" />
        <TextBox Text="Bar" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

But that will problably get you some unwanted behaviours.

Comment: i want the entire control should come in a single cell..! that is, single column.! i want to place the controls whereever i want.

Comment: You cannot "place the controls wherever i want" you need to position them correctly in the XAML